# Screen which element is within a range in R

Tags: r

I would like to ask if there is a way to check for example

```
c(13, 20, 1, 5, 40, 15, 6, 8)
```

is within a range e.g. `> 5` and `<= 30` will give output like below:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just this?

```
x <- c(13, 20, 1, 5, 40, 15, 6, 8)
x > 5 & x <= 30
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

We can also use `between` from `dplyr` or `data.table` but this includes upper and lower boundaries so we can do

```
dplyr::between(x, 6, 31)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or

```
data.table::between(x, 6, 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you omitted a FALSE in your expected result.
But you can achieve that by doing this :

```
c <- c(13, 20, 1, 5, 40, 15, 6, 8)
a <- c > 5 & c <= 30
print(a)
```